# Custom user Login in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 Application, wherein I need every user to be redirected to his custom page upon login. The users are obtained from the UserProfile class which I have refactored into a separate class file. How do I modify the Redirect To method in the Login (post) Action in a ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet Project to get this functionality? Further how do I pass this data to a User controller that can display information related to this specific user.
I'm using simple Membership as it comes out of the box in an internet application template in ASP.NET MVC 4.

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: Ok Teresko point noted, thanks, but could you provide a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're talking about this piece of code in the MVC4 template? I'm doing something very similar - upon login, I redirect the user to a page called `Index.cshtml` listed under the `Account` controller  :

```
[HttpPost, AllowAnonymous, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe))
     { 
         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
     }

      // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
      ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, LocalizedText.Account_Invalid_User_Or_Password);

      return View(model);
}
```

For user specific data, why not just extend the `UsersContext.cs` class in the `Classes` folder, then use `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` to retrieve the information that pertains to that user?

Extended `UsersContext` class :

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsPromotional { get; set; }

    public bool IsAllowShare { get; set; }
}
```

This is the `Index()` action on the `Account` controller that they get redirected to upon login. Here I just call the users context, new up an `AccountModel` that's bound to the Index.cshtml page, set those attributes in the model, then return the View with the model we've built :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   //New up the account model
   var account = new AccountModel();

   try
   {
      //Get the users context
      var CurrentUserId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
      var context = new UsersContext();
      var thisUser = context.UserProfiles.First(p => p.UserId == CurrentUserId);

      //Set the name
      account.Name = thisUser.Name;

      //Set the user specific settings
      account.IsAllowShare = thisUser.IsAllowShare;
      account.IsPromotional = thisUser.IsPromotional;
   }
   catch (Exception exception)
   {
      _logger.Error(exception, "Error building Account Model");
   }
   return View(account);
}
```

It may not be exactly what you're looking for, but that should get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: Hi X3074861X,This surely gets me excited, but am a little confused as to what do you have in this AccountModel class that you're newwing up?

Comment: Hey thanks mate, I actually got it to work, This is the piece of code that I used in the User Controller.

Public ActionResult Index()
{ var account = new UserProfile();
var userid = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
var thisuser = db.UserProfiles.First(p => p.UserId == userid);
return View(thisuser);
}

Comment: I believe I answered the question appropriately, even if you only used part of it. No credit?

Comment: I can't seem to find the Accept button in my account to offer you the credits, guess I dont have enough credits on my account for the Accept answer button to be visible. I'm not sure exactly what's wrong here.